# codename one: how do we scan fingerprints upto three times if fingerprint failed to scan?

Tags: codenameone

[image][image]It's not working properly.I want to scan finger print on form open.On successful finger print scan "Home" form should open and on failed it should scan finger print again three times until successful scan and after successive three failed scans it should go to "Login" form for asking credential. In my case it working differently on different devices.On older android OS it's working partially. On latest android OS failed message comes three time before finger print scan. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.
  int fingerPrintCounter=0;

```
@Override
```

protected void postFinerPrint(Form f) {

```
while(fingerPrintCounter<3){
        fingerPrintCounter++;
fingerPrintScanner();       //finger print scanner method
}
if(!fingerPrintStatus)
{
   showForm("Login", null);
}
```

}

private void fingerPrintScanner() {

```
if (!Fingerprint.isAvailable()) {
    fingerPrintCounter=3;       
    showForm("Login", null);

} else {
    Fingerprint.scanFingerprint("Use your finger print", value -> {
        fingerPrintCounter=3;
        showForm("Home",null)
    }, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
        if (Dialog.show("SCAN FAILED", "Please try again", "OK", null)) {   
            fingerPrintStatus=false;                    
        }

    }, false);

}
```

}

Comment: Which failed message? Is it ours or the OS native message? Screenshots would help to clarify this

Comment: Fingerprint scanner works successfully up to android version 5.1.1 and above that version it doesn't work properly.                                                             After fingerprint scan failed the fingerprint scan failed message comes in loop repeatedly when you first time click ok button that is not goes to login form. I provide a problem in a diagram form and code also. so please tell solution on this problem.

Comment: I provided code and diagram that is problem occure to me. At scanning fail condition,  we run scanner up to 3 times in code  but after 3 times failing it doesn't stop and still continue to display fail message and doesn't go to login form. we gave code and above and digramatic scenario of problem. please tell a solution.

Comment: I'll need to see screenshots of the messages to understand who sent them. Whether it's out library code or Android's subsystem

Comment: I implemented  codename library which i give the code to above. their is problem comes when fingerprint scan failed 3 times and it ask to security pin. At that time if I scan fingerprint they scan goes to fingerprint event but i want to kill that fingerprint event when ask to security code but it doesn't happen. how can i stop that fingerprint event after 3 times failed scanning? This problem comes to after the android version 5.1. It still work up to android version 5.1.

Comment: I need to understand whether our code or the Android native code is responsible for this message. Again. Screenshots of "working" and "not working" versions would help...

Comment: Above i gave you screen shot of message that pop up after fingerprint scan failed but its not a system generated message. that message provided by me in Dialog.show(" ").

Comment: I don't see the screenshot just a drawing and some code but I think I understand your question better now.

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint retries and security pin fallback are builtin to the low level native API we use. Looking at this briefly I didn't spot a way to block the pin fallback behavior as it's builtin to the native code.

This is our implementation code for Android https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner/blob/master/native/android/com/codename1/fingerprint/impl/InternalFingerprintImpl.java

Looking at the native code it doesn't seem like they provide an option to control this but maybe there is a different API you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html